# Drag and Drop Issue in Android Puzzle Game Implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop

I am currently working on developing a simple puzzle game for Android devices using Android Studio. My primary challenge lies in implementing the drag-and-drop functionality for rearranging puzzle pieces.

To provide some context, the existing code successfully splits a user-selected image into a 5 by 5 grid (modifiable dimensions). Additionally, the code shuffles the pieces while maintaining the original 5 by 5 grid format. However, I encounter an issue when attempting to implement the drag-and-drop feature to enable users to reorder the pieces by swapping them.

The problem manifests after successfully dragging a piece; when dropped, the pieces do not swap positions as expected.
[shuffled pieces of tree clipart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5epv4.jpg)

As an individual with limited experience in both Kotlin and Android app development, the majority of the implementation has been carried out through ChatGPT. Despite efforts, the issue persists. Below is a main file of the code I have written for reference:

```
// MainActivity.kt
package com.example.stickman2

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.DragEvent
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.GridLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var selectedImageUri: Uri? = null
    private lateinit var puzzleGridLayout: GridLayout
    private lateinit var puzzlePieces: MutableList<ImageView>
    private lateinit var chooseImageButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        chooseImageButton = findViewById(R.id.chooseImageButton)
        puzzleGridLayout = findViewById(R.id.puzzleGridLayout)
        puzzlePieces = mutableListOf()

        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener {
            openGallery()
        }
    }

    private fun shufflePuzzlePieces() {
        puzzlePieces.shuffle()
        updatePuzzleGridLayout()
    }

    private fun updatePuzzleGridLayout() {
        puzzleGridLayout.removeAllViews()

        for (piece in puzzlePieces) {
            puzzleGridLayout.addView(piece)
        }
    }

    private fun openGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        resultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private val resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                if (data != null) {
                    val imageUri: Uri? = data.data
                    if (imageUri != null) {
                        handleImageSelection(imageUri)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private fun handleImageSelection(imageUri: Uri) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image selected: $imageUri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        selectedImageUri = imageUri

        puzzlePieces.clear()
        puzzleGridLayout.removeAllViews()

        chooseImageButton.visibility = View.GONE

        generatePuzzlePieces(imageUri)

        shufflePuzzlePieces()

        enableDragAndDrop()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun generatePuzzlePieces(imageUri: Uri) {
        val selectedImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)

        val numRows = 5
        val numCols = 5

        val pieceWidth = selectedImageBitmap.width / numCols
        val pieceHeight = selectedImageBitmap.height / numRows

        for (row in 0 until numRows) {
            for (col in 0 until numCols) {
                val x = col * pieceWidth
                val y = row * pieceHeight

                val puzzlePieceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    selectedImageBitmap,
                    x, y, pieceWidth, pieceHeight
                )

                val puzzlePieceImageView = ImageView(this)
                puzzlePieceImageView.setImageBitmap(puzzlePieceBitmap)
                puzzlePieceImageView.layoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams().apply {
                    width = pieceWidth
                    height = pieceHeight
                }

                puzzlePieceImageView.id = row * numCols + col

                puzzlePieceImageView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
                            val dragShadowBuilder = View.DragShadowBuilder(v)
                            v.startDragAndDrop(clipData, dragShadowBuilder, v, 0)
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false
                    }
                }

                puzzleGridLayout.addView(puzzlePieceImageView)
                puzzlePieces.add(puzzlePieceImageView)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun enableDragAndDrop() {
        puzzleGridLayout.setOnDragListener { v, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                    try {
                        val draggedPiece = event.localState as ImageView
                        val droppedArea = v as? ImageView ?: return@setOnDragListener false

                        if (draggedPiece != droppedArea) {
                            val draggedIndex = puzzlePieces.indexOf(draggedPiece)
                            val droppedIndex = puzzlePieces.indexOf(droppedArea)

                            if (draggedIndex != -1 && droppedIndex != -1) {
                                puzzlePieces.swap(draggedIndex, droppedIndex)
                                updatePuzzleGridLayout()

                                if (isPuzzleSolved()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Puzzle Solved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("Drag and Drop", "Error during drop: ${e.message}", e)
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        }

        for (piece in puzzlePieces) {
            piece.setOnLongClickListener { v ->
                try {
                    val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
                    val dragShadowBuilder = View.DragShadowBuilder(v)
                    v.startDragAndDrop(clipData, dragShadowBuilder, v, 0)
                    true
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("Drag and Drop", "Error during drag start: ${e.message}", e)
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun <T> MutableList<T>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
        val temp = this[index1]
        this[index1] = this[index2]
        this[index2] = temp
    }

    private fun isPuzzleSolved(): Boolean {
        return puzzlePieces.indices.all { puzzlePieces[it].id == it }
    }

    // ... rest of your code ...
}
```